# Angular, get html tag embedded data on click event

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling, angular9

I want to make a general click event which work for different tables.
For example I have a table with name = '**tableA**' and another table with name ='**tableB**'
and if I click on **tableA's** td, it should copy whatever is inside **Some Value**
And store it in a local variable, I want the values to be like this:

```
tableName : string = 'tableA';
tdValue : string = 'Some Value';
```

I am comparatively new to angular, and I need to find proper approach and method to do this.
What I intend to do with it ?:
I have imported a few subgraphs via iframes, and I want that whenever a user click on td, they should be redirected to the main subgraph and have search input as whatever is in td.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding, right?

Comment: @LingVu I am not looking for that.

Comment: You do need event binding for this. In the table markup you want to do something like `(click)="copyRowData('tableA', row)"` where `row` is the template variable (or use row.XX if you only need the value of one column) and than you can extract/remodel the data to your desired format. (The binding would either be on the tr or on the td)